# C# won't read updated version of SQL variable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

## Resolved - was querying the wrong DB by mistake

sorry for wasting your time! :(

---

I'm trying to read the results of a series of actions on a SQL variable, this is the query i'm trying to get the value out of:

```sql
DECLARE @Count INT = 0 
IF EXISTS(SELECT name FROM sys.sysobjects WHERE Name = N'Table1' AND xtype = N'U')
BEGIN   
    SET @Count = @Count + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1)
END 
IF EXISTS(SELECT name FROM sys.sysobjects WHERE Name = N'Table2' AND xtype = N'U')
BEGIN   
    SET @Count = @Count + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2)
END 
IF EXISTS(SELECT name FROM sys.sysobjects WHERE Name = N'Table3' AND xtype = N'U')
BEGIN   
    SET @Count = @Count + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table3)
END 
SELECT @Count
```

Basically it checks if a bunch of tables (which might not exist) have rows in them.

---

### C# Code

```cs
List<string> queries = new List<string>();
foreach (var table in tables)
{
    queries.Add(string.Format(@"IF EXISTS(SELECT name FROM sys.sysobjects WHERE Name = N'{0}' AND xtype = N'U')
                                BEGIN   
                                    SET @Count = @Count + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0})
                                END", table.Name.Trim()));
}

var queryString = string.Format(@"DECLARE @Count INT = 0 {0} SELECT @Count
                                    GO", string.Join(" ", queries));

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    //I also tried these methods using Dapper:
    // int count = connection.Query<int>(queryString);
    // int count = (int)connection.ExecuteScalar(queryString);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);

        //dt has one row where the data is 0, not the sum as i want it
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

---

### The Problem

The problem is, no matter how I try to load the result in C# the original value always gets returned (in this case 0, but if i change it in the query the change gets reflected in the result).

I'd like for the returned value to be the sum of all these queries:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM X)
```

---

### What I tried

1. Searching online i thought it was a scope problem, so i tried running the query with and without SqlCommand parameters, which didn't change the outcome, maybe i'm not searching the right words
2. Adding 'GO' both after the SET commands and at the end
3. Trying different ways to parse the data in the ASP.NET application, including using an external library, called Dapper

Putting the query in a stored procedure is not possible unfortunately, anyone has an idea about what to try next? I've been stuck on this for a while...

> SQL Server version is SQLServer 2014

Comment: We need code, please post what you've tried.

Comment: In c# you have two commands 1) Insert 2) Update.  When using ExecuteNonQuery() you have to check the return value which is the number of rows affected.  If you get a return value of zero it means no rows changed.   If you are doing an INSERT it means the key already exists in the table and then you have to use UPDATE to   change the existing key value.  If you are doing UPDATE it means the key doesn't exist in table and then you have to do a INSERT to put a new key into the table.

Comment: *no matter how I try to load the result in C# the original value always gets returned* where is this C# you talk of?

Comment: I've updated my answer based on the edits...

Comment: Make your c# this: `var queryString = string.Format(@"DECLARE @Count INT = 0 {0} SELECT CONCAT('There are ',@Count,' matching rows in the tables tried'); GO", string.Join(" ", queries));` and tell us what the result in the datatable is then

Comment: I suspect the datatable's first/only cell will say "There are 0 matching rows in the tables tried" - in which case it isn't a c# problem. Are you sure there are matching rows? Have you extracted the sql the c# is running and debugged it in SSMS?

Comment: Set a breakpoint before the `using`, copy the value of `queryString` to the clipboard and execute this on the same database using the same database user in a separate tool. What is the result then? I expect you will also get 0 then. So, this is not a C# Question then, but one about SQL Server. Maybe the problem is that in the resulting string, there are no line breaks or semicolons between the individual statements. Have you tried explicitly using semicolons to separate the SQL statements?

Comment: Also, make sure you're executing the query on the same database that C# is; wouldn't be the first time I've had someone say "oh, i was testing the query on my prod DB with 4252 rows but I forgot my local debug DB that c# was using is actually empty..."

Comment: ps; I always found `using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter(strSql, strConn)){ var dt = new DataTable(); da.Fill(dt); }` to be easier than bothering with datareaders

Comment: @CaiusJard I cant believe that got past me, thank you! and sorry for making you waste your time on my stupidity ;_;

Comment: Lol, well.. we got there in the end. Might have cost $500 when you add up the contract rate of the professionals involved but **we've all done it**. My favorite, back in the old days of file based DB (access, or localdb/attached sqlserver ones) was having the DB in the c# project and "Copy Always" set on the file as a build action, so the DB file in the debug dir was always overwritten by the build process. *Why won't my stupid c# program save the data, Argh! Every time I start my project the data I just saved is gone!* ... *Oh. Yeah. Copy-If-Newer. Must remember that*

Comment: A DataTable is a higher overhead than a DataReader, using it entails making a fairly complex object, laden with junk that you are going to very quickly throw away again without ever needing - depends how often it gets executed of course though

Comment: @Cato Yes i'm aware, i was just desperate to get the data out, will revert to ExecuteScalar casted to int now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edit to reflect the question edits:

With the change shown, and:

```
//dt has one row where the data is 0, not the sum as i want it
```

then: the answer is zero. You're querying it in an OK way (the `DataTable` is massively overkill, but... meh), but: *the answer is zero*.

I'm pretty sure that if you run the same TSQL in SSMS (in the same database, as the same user): you'll get zero there, too.

---

Ultimately, the key factor here is: how are you returning the value? In this case, you are doing:

```
SELECT @Count
```

which means that it is going to be coming back as a results grid - i.e. it is a *query*; so: as long as you use a *query* API, you should be fine. This includes `ExecuteScalar` in ADO.NET, and `QuerySingle<int>` in dapper (which you mention).

What you *can't* do is use the return value of `ExecuteNonQuery` (`Execute` in dapper), as this is an unrelated value (and is usually wrong and/or empty and/or useless - don't use it pretty much ever).

Comment: Oh, i dunno.. ExecuteNonQuery on a CRUD is pretty vital for getting optimistic concurrency to work out properly

Comment: @CaiusJard nothing wrong with `ExecuteNonQuery`, but the *return value* is not guaranteed to be set at all; if you want to know a rowcount, for example, then I would **strongly** recomment `select @@rowcount` - or if you really want to use `ExecuteNonQuery`, `set @someOutArg = @@rowcount`, or `return @@rowcount`, which is accessed virtually identically to the `@someOutArg` API, and is *not* the return value of `ExecuteNonQuery`

Comment: OK.. Though have you ever run an plain old `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` query and NOT had ExecuteNonQuery return the number of rows affected?

Comment: thanks for the reply, unfortunately (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() still returns 0

Comment: @CaiusJard yes, very often; a: a lot of places make it standard practice to `SET NOCOUNT ON` to slightly reduce TDS traffic; b: if tables have *triggers*, those triggers can cause very confusing results from this

Comment: @HiSpy refresh the page; that's because zero *is the answer*

Comment: Extracting the query from the c# code and running it from SqlManager returns 4252, is there something i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this C# (might have minor syntax errors - didn't write/run it in VS). If you still get 0 out of it, you're querying an empty db:

```
int count = 0;
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    try{
        connection.Open();
        foreach (var table in tables)
        {

            try{
                var cmd = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + table;
                using(var sc as new SqlCommand(cmd, connection)){
                    count += (int)sc.ExecuteScalar();
                }
            }
            catch {}
        }
    }finally{
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way here is to attach your sql to a command, then do

```
int retVal = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

should get the value back fine - it's one of several ways of doing it though.

ExecuteScalar is for instances where you want to return a single row with a single column, as you have done here.

Comment: have you confirmed zero is not the value in the variable?  Try doing SET @COUNT=1; the line before you SELECT it, as a check.